# Pattern for comparing multiple partial lists of strings to a primary one

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns, comparison

So I have an 'uber' list: DestinationColumn, with 100 strings. Always 100, let's say, for simplicity.

It comes from several source columns, ColA, ColB.  Some of those will have 100 strings, some will have less.

So, example:

ColA has values for strings 1-33, 40-70, and 90-100.  It gets first priority, and fills in all the values into DestinationColumn for those strings.
ColB has values for 1-40, and 70-100.  Where a gap exists, it fills it in, but it must't overwite ColA strings.

Now I want to make sure this has happened.

List sourceColA, List sourceColB
and ListdestinationColumn.

Firstly I wrote a function to compare two lists to see if they contain the same strings:

```
public static bool ListEquals<T>(IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
    {
        if ((list1 == null) || (list2 == null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
            return false;
        for (int i = list1.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (!list1[i].Equals(list2[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now I want to keep it as generic as that, but take x source columns, and make sure all the content is now correctly in the one destination column. Is there a general pattern for doing such?

My current thinking is a loop, marking off all of ColA's entries against the destinationCol, repeating for B, and so on, and then making sure all entries are not hit twice and that all entries are hit once.

Answer (score 1):

To merge two columns as you describe you could do it as simply as

```
ColA.Zip(ColB, (a, b) => a??b)
```

So:

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> cols=
        new string[][]
        {
            new string[]{"monkey", "frog", null, null, null, null},
            new string[]{null, null, null, null, "cat", "giraffe"},
            new string[]{null, null, null, "dog", "fish", null}
        };
    cols.MergeLeft().Dump();
    //gives: "monkey", "frog", null, "dog", "cat", "giraffe" 


}

static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MergeLeft<T>
        (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> cols) where T:class
    {
        var maxItems = cols.Max(x => x.Count());
        var leftMerged = 
            cols
                .Aggregate(
                    Enumerable.Repeat((T)null, maxItems),
                    (acc,col) => acc.Zip(col, (a, b) => a ?? b));
        return leftMerged;

    }
}
```

EDIT

Here's a more efficient version of `MergeLeft` that doesn't require `maxItems` eliminating the expense described below by @Enigmativity:

```
static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MergeLeft<T>
        (this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> cols) where T:class
    {
        return cols
            .Aggregate(
                Enumerable.Empty<T>(),
                (acc,col) => 
                acc
                    .Concat(Infinite<T>(null))
                    .Zip(col, (a, b) => a ?? b));   
    }
    private static IEnumerable<T> Infinite<T>(T item)
    {
        for(;;){yield return item;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but the `var maxItems` line is very expensive and it is possible to have "hot" enumerables that change value between iterations. It may be worth pushing `cols` to an array and start with the zeroth column as the initial aggregate accumulator - then `Zip` can just work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you are trying to do, since I don't understand the purpose of your ListEquals. Anyway, I'd go this way:

```
    public static void FillDest<T>(IList<T> dest, IList<IList<T>> srcLists)
        where T : class
    {
        bool goon = true;
        int idx = 0;
        dest.Clear();
        while (goon)
        {
            goon = false;
            bool added = true;
            foreach (IList<T> aSrc in srcLists)
            {
                added = false;
                T anItem;
                if (aSrc.Count <= idx)
                {
                    added = true;
                    continue;
                }
                goon = true;
                if ((anItem = aSrc[idx]) != null)
                {
                    dest.Add(anItem);
                    added = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!added)
                dest.Add((T)null);
            idx++;
        }
    }
```